# jQuery - append div into hidden, diplay none, element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to insert a "div" in a container "div" which is set to "display none" but does not work.

Can someone help me?

```
<div id="container" class="container" style="display:none"></div>

<script>

var array = [];

var k = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) {

array.push("<div>item</div>");

}

$("#container").append(array);

</script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: It will work when you show that div. After appending also try, `$("#container").show();`

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to add a javascript array as html into the div. That is not possible, simply because a javascript variable is not a html element.

To make the array into a string (which you can add), simply use `join`

```
$("#container").append( array.join("") );
```

Small edit to be sure: The div is still hidden, but it has the elements, to make those visible you have to change the css to make it visible. To achief that:

```
$("#container").append( array.join("") ).show();
```